# rounding down and rounding up a number in Python

Tags: python

Given an input number x, find the rounding up and rounding down number (python)
using the following method.

```
math.floor(x * (10 ** y)) / (10.0 ** y)
math.ceil(x * (10 ** y)) / (10.0 ** y)
```

Comment: Rounding -0.000044 up to the nearest int is 0. Rounding -0.000044 down to one decimal place is -0.1.

Comment: 0.0 looks right to me. Did you actually want "round away from zero" and "round toward zero"?

Comment: I guess that depends on how you define "up" and "down" for negative numbers. If your definition is different than Python's, just multiply negative numbers by -1 both before and after the rounding. (i.e. round their absolute values, then make them negative again)

Comment: It's pretty well defined, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it depends on how you define "up" and "down" whether negative numbers should be rounded up to the "more positive" numbers, or the number with larger absolute value. If your definition is different than [the usual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions#Examples), just multiply negative numbers by -1 both before and after the rounding, i.e. round their absolute values, then make them negative again.

```
def round_up(x, y=0):
    if x < 0:
        return -round_up(-x, y)
    return math.ceil(x * (10 ** y)) / (10 ** y)
```

Doing the same for `round_down` is left as an exercise for the reader. Also note that `y=0` would in fact round to the nearest integer; if you want `-0.1`, use `y=1` instead.